# Populating a SwiftUI Picker with Calendars

Tags: swift, swiftui, calendar

I am trying to populate a SwiftUI picker with a list of calendars.

As far as I can tell, the process should be something like this:

- Declare an array of calendars:
- Populate the array in the view’s `onAppear` method
- Populate the picker from the array.

I can’t get anything to work without some fundamental error. My code goes something like this:

Create the variable at the top level:

```swift
let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
let sources = eventStore.sources

var calendars: [EKCalendar] = []
```

In the `.onAppear()` method populate the variable:

```swift
for source in sources {
    calendars = calendars + source.calendars(for: .event).sorted{ $0.title < $1.title }
}
```

Populate the picker:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var calendar: EKCalendar!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select a calendar", selection: $calendar) {
                
//              ForEach(calendars) { calendar in
//                  Text("hahaha")
//                  Text(calendar.title)
//              }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
    }
}
```

The commented out code above doesn’t work. How can I populate the picker?

Comment: You need to pass the array down.

Comment: @loremipsum Ho do I do that?

Comment: Similar to what you did with Binding just use a “let”. You might want to start with some tutorials. Passing arguments down is like Day 1 of any course. Hacking with Swift has something like “100 days”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example approach, having the selection `calendar` and the `calendars` in your
`ContentView`, at least as a test.
Note the importance of having a `.tag(Optional(calendar))` in the Picker.

Of course you will need to have the Calendar enabled in your App Sandbox settings,
and have some calendars in your EKEventStore, otherwise you will see only "no selection".

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var calendar: EKCalendar? // <--- here
    @State private var calendars: [EKCalendar] = [] // <--- here

   let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select a calendar", selection: $calendar) {
                Text("no selection").tag(Optional<EKCalendar>.none)
                ForEach(calendars, id: \.self) { calendar in
                    Text(calendar.title)
                        .tag(Optional(calendar)) // <--- here
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)
        }
        .onAppear {
            // --- here
            for source in eventStore.sources {
                calendars = calendars + source.calendars(for: .event).sorted{ $0.title < $1.title }
            }
            print("----> calendars: \(calendars.count)") // for testing info
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you will also need to grant (request from the user) permission to access the various
Calendars.

Comment: Excellent. I still need to get my head around the changes you suggested, but they worked, and I can move on. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear you are making progress.
 Note, SwiftUI is probably very different to what you are used to.
 Understanding the fundamental of the SwiftUI user interface framework,
 such as the automatic update of the UI views as the data changes, is very important.
 Do some tutorials first, before you start coding your App, it will pay well.
Note also, do not (should not) have those `floating` nowhere top level
 variable, this is not how SwiftUI works.